# How can I store other information on a model instance in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Let's say we have two models

```
const instance1 = Model1.create({id: 1, someInfo: "something important"});
const instance2 = Model2.create({id: 1});

//  In another file.
Model2.addHook('beforeCreate', function (instance2, options){
     // I want to access instance1 here.
})
```

Now, there is no association between Model1 and Model2, and Model2 has a beforeCreate hook where i want to access the instance1. These create operations also going to use transaction.

Which is the proper way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Because the `options` are passed to the hook you can set one of the properties to be your first instance.

This is the model definition that sets up the hook, grabbing your custom properties from the options.

```js
Model2.addHook('beforeCreate', async function(instance2, options){
   const { details, transaction } = options;
   const { instance } = details;
   // `instance` will be the `instance1` you passed in
});
```

Once you create the first instance you can pass it to the second in the options. If you are using a transaction you will want to pass it through as well, note that updates won't be available outside the transaction until it is committed. You will also need to `await` the results of the `Model.create()`.

```js
const transaction = await sequelize.transaction();

const instance1 = await Model1.create({ id: 1, someInfo: "something important" }, {
  transaction,
});

const instance2 = await Model2.create({ id: 1 }, {
  details: {
    instance: instance1,
  },
  transaction,
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. but is it a good practice to add our own properties to options object?

Comment: I think it depends on how you do it, as long as you use a property that doesn't conflict with the Sequelize options then there shouldn't be an issue. It's not guaranteed to be safe though, but it's also the only way to do the thing you want to do - other than using more complex caching or something.

Comment: In just another similar scenario, can you get a model's instance of a table that is already in a remote database. Im able to connect to a remote db. But instead of directly using query method to write extensive plain sql queries, can I use the ORM like functionality to query data from an existing table without defining the model in my app?

Comment: In just another similar scenario, can you get a model's instance of a table that is already in a remote database. Im able to connect to a remote db. But instead of directly using query method to write extensive plain sql queries, can I use the ORM like functionality to query data from an existing table without defining the model in my app?
I meant something like instead of using like 
sequelize.models.query("SELECT * FROM <tablename>" )
using something like:
await <table_name>.findAll({
        where: {
          userid: id
        }
});

Comment: @ShyamSundarR all of the databases are technically "remote" services even if they are on the same machine. The Instance object is just a copy of the data in the database, so you can fetch it from anywhere and then pass it through to a different database query, but that database just wouldn't be able to refer to it in SQL.

Comment: @doublesharp, what I mentioned was slightly deviated from the above stuff you had mentioned. Its in detail in the following link:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/280081/how-do-i-use-sequelize-npm-package-to-access-an-existing-table-in-a-remote-herok?noredirect=1#comment547368_280081
. I know that the objects can be fetched from anywhere. Im mainly concerned about the methods or the syntaxes used to fetch them and asking the possibility of the ORM syntax without defining the model in the application.

Comment: You can use a raw query and it will just return JSON without defining a model: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html